# def vs lazy val in case class

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, function

I have a DAO object which I defined as a case class.

```
case class StudentDAO(id: Int) {
  def getGPA: Double = // Expensive database lookup goes here
  def getRank: Int = // Another expensive database operation and computation goes here
  def getScoreCard: File = // Expensive file lookup goes here
}
```

I would naturally make `getGPA` and `getRank` and `getScoreCard` `def`s and not `val`s because I don't want them to be computed before they may be used.

What would be the performance impact if I marked these methods as `lazy val`s instead of `def`s? The reason I want to make them `lazy val`s is: I do not want to recompute the rank each time for a Student with id "i".

I am hoping that this will not be marked as duplicate because there are several questions as below which are mostly about differences:

[When to use val, def, and lazy val in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291831/when-to-use-val-def-and-lazy-val-in-scala)

[def or val or lazy val for grammar rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188964/def-or-val-or-lazy-val-for-grammar-rules)

[`def` vs `val` vs `lazy val` evaluation in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449474/def-vs-val-vs-lazy-val-evaluation-in-scala)

[Scala Lazy Val Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731389/scala-lazy-val-question)

This question is mainly aimed towards the expenses (tradeoffs between CPU vs. memory) in making a `method` a `lazy val` for costly operations and what would one suggest over other and why?

EDIT: Thank you for the comment @om-nom-nom. I should have been more clear with what I was looking for.

I read here:

[Use of lazy val for caching string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883185/use-of-lazy-val-for-caching-string-representation)

that string representation of the object is cached (see [@Dave Griffith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3883514/65299)). More precisely I am looking at the impact of Garbage Collection if I made it a `lazy val` instead of `def`

Comment: What are you expect to hear? *lazy val will cost you 10 more bytes and 200 CPU cycles?*

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Not exactly. Please see my edit :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward to me:

> I don't want them to be computed before they may be
>   used.
>   [...]
>   I do not want to recompute the rank each time for a Student with id "i".

Then use `lazy val` and that's it.

`def` is used when the value may change for each call, typically because you pass parameters, `val` won't change but will be computed right away.

Comment: So it makes sense to make it `def` instead of `lazy val` because the value may change ? Then it better be a `def`! What about the impact on garbage collection ? Please see my edit.

Comment: If the value may change then it is definitely a `def`. A `val` will be computed once and that's it.

Comment: Makes sense. Say if the value is not going to change and I want to use `lazy val` instead of `def`, what is the impact on GC ?

Comment: It would be an attribute for your instance, it would not be garbage collected until there is no more reference to your `StudentDAO`.

Comment: If the value can be recomputed but you want to hold on to the computed value unless the GC needs memory, have a look at `WeakReference`

Answer (score 3):

A `lazy val` for an "ordinary" reference type (e.g., `File`) has the effect of creating a strong reference the first time it is evaluated. Thus, while it will avoid re-evaluations of an unchanging value, it has the obvious cost of keeping the computed value in memory.

For primitive values (or even lightweight objects, like `File`), this memory cost usually isn't much of an issue (unless you're holding lots of `Student` objects in memory). For a heavy reference, though (e.g., a large data structure), you might be better off using a weak reference, some other caching approach, or just computing the value on-demand.